# PHP Change Max File Size Upload

Tags: php

I am developing a web site. It will be deployed offline. It's just like a interface for image and video storage.

When I upload files, this is what happens. [Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukHsO.png)

[image]
It exceeds the maximum file size. I want to change the maximum file size anywhere I deploy it. Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using .htaccess file in the root directory, you can increase the maximum upload size

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

other way change 
php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size =64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following settings in your php.ini file

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: where is it exactly located ?

Comment: @marklacerna How have you got your local server setup ?

Comment: im developing it with xampp. how do I do it ?

Comment: @marklacerna Create a php file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, and look for the `Loaded Configuration File` setting. That should give you the path to php.ini. Alternatively you could try using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in your PHP code

Answer (score 1):

go to xampp/php/php.ini, open php.ini using a text editor and find this line upload_max_filesize=, set the file size what you want